# Exec shell script with different user using Apache

Tags: php, bash, apache

[Mac OS 13.10.3, PHP7.1, Apache 2.4]

I'm using a php script to reorganise some files I have scattered around various places in my home directory structure.  The php part, first performs some *complicated* logic which I don't think bash could do efficiently, and then calls a bash script to perform the final move operations I need done.

When I run the php script from the command line, it works fine.  However, I would like to be able to run it through my localhost apache httpd server, so I can get nicer rendering of the results of the various operations in my browser.

When I invoke the php script via my browser, the bash script returns with permission errors.  Initially I thought I could fix this by setting the `setuid` bit on the bash script, but this didn't work and the script still runs under the apache userid. (More info [here about `setuid` with scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts/2910#2910).)

There are some things I don't want to do:
1) Change permissions in my home directories to enable this to work,
2) Give the apache user `sudo` access to the `/bin/mv` command, etc.

I'm wondering what else can I do to enable the script to perform the moves?

-=-=-

The php test script inside my DocumentRoot:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$shellResult = array();
$shellReturn = 0;
exec("/Users/user/myScripts/move \"" . "/Users/user/myScripts/mytest.pdf" ."\" \"". "/Users/user/myScripts/testDir" ."\" \"". "aNew.pdf" . "\"", $shellResult, $shellReturn);
echo var_dump($shellResult);
echo $shellReturn;

?>
```

The *move* bash script in */Users/user/myScripts*:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

echo -e `whoami`
echo -e "$2"
echo -e "$3"

if [ ! -e "$1" ] ; then
    echo "$1"
    exit 3
else 
    if [ -e "$2/$3" ] ; then
        echo "$1"
        exit 4
    fi
fi
echo -e "MOVING\n"
/bin/mv "$1" "$2/$3"
```

The result I get in the browser (note the error **1** returned at the end)

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "_www"
  [1]=>
  string(28) "/Users/user/myScripts/testDir"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "aNew.pdf"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "MOVING"
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
}
1
```

Comment: Are you full admin?  If so configure `sudo` to allow your apache running user to switch to the proper user required for your script to run.  Or assign the apache running user a group and set group permissions to allow to run.

Comment: Yea, I can modify `sudoers` but I prefer not to, and another way to do something similar is to set the apache userid to use my account.  But I'm wondering how something like this might be done in a production environment.